# Substring in Excel2010

Tags: string, excel

I'm working on an Excel file and I need to seperate a long string divided by "|" into different strings
for example:
"AB100|AB101|AB102|AB103"

I need to seperate them into - AB100, AB101, AB102, AB103

Thank you!

Comment: @apomene not sure how that solves the original problem, solves the inverse though.

Comment: @xlm you sre right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Ribbon, under the 'Data' tab, select 'Text to Columns' and select the appropriate delimiter, in this case it is `|`

Illustrative screenshot on where to find it and the output:
[image]

Note I have done it with two copies of your example string to show a before and after. It will replace the original string in `A1` with the values split across the columns.

Comment: Works Like a charm - it's always great to learn new things :)
TNX!!

Answer (score 0):

With your data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"|",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))
```

and copy across.